# Unexpected behaviour of Nothing inside List inside Association

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations

When evaluating the following input:

```
<|a -> {c, d, e}|> /. d -> Nothing
```

I get (expression 1):

```
<|a -> {c, Nothing, e}|>
```

However I would expect to get (expression 2):

```
<|a -> {c, e}|>
```

Nevertheless, if i place the cursor on the unexpected output (expression 1) and evaluate it by pressing Shift + Enter, I get the expected output (expression 2), which is even more puzzling.

Mathematica version is 11.0.0.0

Should this behaviour be expected or is it a bug? Why?

Comment: closely related: [Pattern matching to a function evaluation inside an Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128453/125)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The observed puzzle is resolved by the following two observations:

From Leonid's answer in the linked q/a:

> - `Association` is `HoldAllComplete`. Once it is created, its parts will then normally be held unevaluated.

From [`Nothing`>> Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html)

> - Nothing *is removed as part of the standard evaluation process. It is not removed in expressions that are held or inactive*.

You can `Map` `ReplaceAll` on the association to force removal of `Nothing`s:

```
ReplaceAll[d -> Nothing] /@ assoc (* or *)
Map[# /. d -> Nothing &]@<|a -> {c, d, e}|>
```

> <|a -> {c, e}|>

Answer (score 5):

Use `Replace` with level spec `All` rather than `ReplaceAll`:

```
Replace[<|a -> {c, d, e}|>, d -> Nothing, All]
```

> <|a -> {c, e}|>

Related: [Is there a difference between Replace with parameter "All" and ReplaceAll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188605)

Answer (score 3):

[Pattern matching to a function evaluation inside an Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128453/125) answers your question about bug vs expected result.

This will not do what your input suggests but let me anticipate your needs:

```
<|a -> {b, c, d}, e :> {d, Print[1], d}, f -> d|> //. 
  {a___, d, b___} :> {a, b} /. (*this way Print is not evaluated*)
  d -> Nothing
```

> ```
> <|a -> {b, c}, e :> {Print[1]}, f -> Nothing|>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness sakes (I believe Coolwater's answer is best):

```
assoc = Association[ a → {c,d,e} ];
```

**Query**

```
assoc // Query[ All, ReplaceAll[ d → Nothing ] ]

(* <|a -> {c, e}|> *)
```

Note:  This will need repeated use of `All` for nested associations.

**DeleteCases**

Before there was `Nothing` there was `DeleteCases` and the like:

```
assoc // DeleteCases[ #, d, Infinity ]&

(* <|a -> {c, e}|> *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Query` to evaluate the result of the replace in an `Association`. `Query` gives direct access to the key's value which then evaluated in `Query`.

```
Query[All, # /. d -> Nothing &]@<|a -> {c, d, e}|>
```

> ```
> <|a -> {c, e}|>
> ```

Hope this helps.