# Replace vs. ReplaceAll involving Flat

Tags: pattern-matching, attributes

I'm aware that `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` behave differently as discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/), but still get confused with the following example when `Flat` is involved:

```
f//Attributes = {Flat, OneIdentity};

Replace[f[x, 2 y, z], f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y], {0, Infinity}]
(* f[x, 2 y, z] *)

ReplaceAll[f[x, 2 y, z], f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y]]
(* f[x, y, z] *)
```

The result of `ReplaceAll` is as expected, but why does `Replace` not try the pattern `f[f[x, 2y], z]`? Is there a simple workaround for `Replace` without modifying the rule?

---

Update 1

A simpler example by @user293787:

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
ReplaceAll[f[a,b],f[a]->0]
(*f[0,b]*)
Replace[f[a,b],f[a]->0,All]
(*f[a,b]*)
```

---

Update 2

It seems that in the sequence inside `f`, a non-`Pattern` head will stop the matching from left to right, e.g.

```
Replace[f[a,b,c],f[a_,b]->g[a,b],All]
(*f[a, b, c]*)
Replace[f[a,b,c],f[a_,c]:>g[a,c],All]
(*g[f[a, b], c]*)
```

(the update 2 is from part of my answer, in which the solution is totally wrong. I delete it to avoid confusions.)

Comment: That is an interesting observation. Related: `f[a,b]/.f[a]->0` gives `f[0,b]` but `Replace[f[a,b],f[a]->0,{0,Infinity}]` gives `f[a,b]`.

Comment: Tangentially related: In [this post from 9 years ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18060)
they say that `SetAttributes[M,{Flat}];Replace[M[F1[a]],M[x_F1]|M[x_F2]->x]` returns `M[F1[a]]`, but if I run it now I get `F1[a]`. Apparently this was "fixed". Perhaps you found a similar problem.

Comment: @user293787, thx! I'll add your simpler example to the question.

Comment: @user293787 Yes, that was fixed. Or possibly "fixed", as you put it; I'm never certain about these changes when it comes to the pattern matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a way to explain the behavior, see [@MichalE2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273596/36508)

The following might be a workaround, at least for the examples in the question. It is based on the observation that a catch-all rule like `x_:>x` stops `ReplaceAll` from matching any parts not on the top level, but doesn't stop "`Flat`-induced" matches:

```
f // Attributes = {Flat, OneIdentity};

ReplaceAll[f[x, 2 y, z], {f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y], x_ :> x}]
(* f[x, y, z] *)

ReplaceAll[{f[x, 2 y, z]}, {f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y], x_ :> x}]
(* {f[x, 2 y, z]} *)
```

Thus:

```
myReplace[expr_, rules_, level_ : {0}] := 
 Map[ReplaceAll[Flatten@{rules, x_ :> x}], expr, level]

myReplace[f[x, 2 y, z], f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y]]
(* f[x, y, z] *)

myReplace[{f[x, 2 y, z]}, f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y]]
(* {f[x, 2 y, z]} *)

myReplace[{f[x, 2 y, z]}, f[x_, 2 y_] :> f[x, y], 1]
(* {f[x, y, z]} *)
```

Comment: Nice. (+1) I've used this trick in other situations. Somehow if replacement is on my mind, I usually do `myReplace` like this: `myReplace[expr_, rules_, level_ : {0}] := Replace[expr, e_ :> (e /. Flatten@{rules, x_ :> x}), level]`. I can't think of any advantage of one over the other, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I guess a minor advantage is the fact that it is more explicit that the level specification is applied correctly. On the other hand, I do find it slightly harder to mentally parse. Other than that, they should indeed behave equivalently as far as I can tell

Comment: I didn't realize there was any difference in how they handled the level spec. (Or I've forgotten the difference.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry for the confusion - I meant to say that while the levelspec behavior is the same for `Map` and `Replace` (as far as I know), it's more obvious that you get the correct behavior if you do actually use `Replace`

Answer (score 2):

> why does `Replace` not try the pattern `f[f[x, 2y], z]`?

First, I don't think `ReplaceAll` does this either. It matches the argument sequence `x, 2y` by virtue of the `Flat` attribute and replaces it by `f[x, y]` according to the OP's rule. Alternatively, we could look at it as matching `Part[f[x, 2y, z], ;; 2]`. Either, I don't think pattern matcher unflattens a flat function. (This is undocumented AFAIK, so I could be mistaken.)

It can do something like the operation in the quote above when carrying out the *replacement.*  Using `TracePrint` on `f[w, x, 2 y, z]` and `f[v, w, x, 2 y, z]`,
we see that `x_` in `f[x_,2 y_]:>f[x,y]` matches `w, x` and replaces them with `Part[f[w, x, 2y, z][[;; 2] or` f[w, x]`, and similarly for` v, w, x`and`f[v, w, x]`.

```
f[w,x,2 y,z] /. f[x_,2 y_]:>f[x,y]
f[f[f[w,x],y],z]

f[v,w,x,2 y,z] /. f[x_,2 y_]:>f[x,y]
f[f[f[v,w,x],y],z]
```

Next to the docs for `Replace`:

> Replace by default applies rules only to complete expressions

Of course `x, 2y` is not a complete expression, and arguably `Part[f[x, 2 y, z], ;; 2]` is *part* of an expression, not a complete expression at any level of `f[x, 2y, z]`.

Unfortunately, the site users who seemed to have authoritative knowledge of the pattern matcher also seem to have left the site. :(

*Workaround?*

I'd use this, but maybe I'm missing something about what the OP wants:

```
Replace[f[x, 2 y, z], f[x_, 2 y_, foo___] :> f[x, y, foo]]
```

Comment: +1. While I think your explanation makes sense, I don't like what it is implying. In my mind, `Replace` is a more controlled version of `ReplaceAll`. However, this behavior means that it is impossible to faithfully apply `DownValues` of a symbol at the top-level only (besides trying to check the expression for its head beforehand or similar). Also, the documentation is not really clear on this (as you point out): For instance, from the documentation of `Flat`: "`Flat` is an attribute... This property is accounted for in pattern matching." - the latter doesn't really seem to be true here

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Thx! In my actual usage the rule is a long list.

Comment: I was unaware that anyone had authoritative knowledge of the pattern matcher. I'm not sure such a background can exist, though to be fair I'm not aware of any non-existence proof either. (Me, I just fix the bugs, I don't pretend to understand much of it. In particular I don't understand the inner doings of `Flat` which, as best I can tell, is the pattern matcher's equivalent to the human limbic system.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau They seemed to know. And when they corrected me, often rather quickly, they seemed to be right. How they came by that knowledge, I don't know. Whether one wants to call it "authoritative," or "divine," or whatever, their knowledge exceeded mine and would still, I believe. (It was a wistful remark recalling good times, which also was meant to invite anyone with a different understanding to disagree and educate me.)