# How to distinguish x[a] from x in replacement rules?

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, rule

Quick to the point:is there a way to make Mathematica assume that $a \neq a[1] \neq a[2] , ...$ I notice that Solve assumes that  $a$ is the same for all $a[1],a[2],...$ Also, if I replace $a \rightarrow b$ then I get all the $b[1],b[2],..$ for the whole expression.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but the question was a bit too quick to the point for me to grasp what the problem is. Consider taking an example as it is difficult to infer context. For example, what is the problem in the  result from `Solve[{x[1] + x[2] == 1, x[1] - x[2] == 2}, {x[1], x[2]}]` ?

Comment: I think I was wrong about Solve, maybe latter I'll post the equation I was trying to solve. However, when you take the solution provided by`Solve[{x + x[2] == 1}, {x}]` and plug back to the equation you get something like `(1- x[2] + (1-x[2])[2])`, that is the main issue I'm having.

Comment: Why not use `Solve[x[1] + x[2] == 1, x[1]]` or `Solve[x1 + x[2] == 1, x1]`. If you already have a long code where you used `x` and `x[2]` you can do `newEquation=oldEquation/.x->x1` solve `newEquation` and then revert back to the previous notation  using `x1->x` whenever you need,

Comment: @userrandrand the x1 will be plugged in the variable x[2], and the result will be `x1[2]`.

Comment: Hi I thought about that after then I forget to add a comment to correct myself here.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from one of the comments above:

> However, when you take the solution provided by `Solve[{x + x[2] == 1}, {x}]` and plug back to the equation you get something like `(1- x[2] + (1-x[2])[2])`, that is the main issue I'm having.

The easy fix is just changing x to something like x1 before using `Solve` but that might be a problem if the expressions are lengthy . Here are some replacement rules that change x to x1 while keeping x[2]:

Reference:

```
Expand[(x + Cos[x[2] + x]*x[2]*x + Sin[x[3]*x])^2 + x]
```

`x+x^2+2 x Sin[x x[3]]+Sin[x x[3]]^2+2 x^2 Cos[x+x[2]] x[2]+2 x Cos[x+x[2]] Sin[x x[3]] x[2]+x^2 Cos[x+x[2]]^2 x[2]^2`

- **Option 1**

Straightforward but clunky as it introduces an auxiliary variable:

```
 expression1=
 (Expand[(x + Cos[x[2] + x]*x[2]*x + Sin[x[3]*x])^2 + x]
 /. x[s_] :> b[s] /. x :> x1 /. b :> x)
```

`x1+x1^2+2 x1 Sin[x1 x[3]]+Sin[x1 x[3]]^2+2 x1^2 Cos[x1+x[2]] x[2]+2 x1 Cos[x1+x[2]] Sin[x1 x[3]] x[2]+x1^2 Cos[x1+x[2]]^2 x[2]^2`

- **Option 2**

Quick but mysterious :

```
expression2=
(Expand[(x + Cos[x[2] + x]*x[2]*x + Sin[x[3]*x])^2 + x] 
/. {x -> x1, x[s_] :> x[s]});
```

It's not entirely clear to me why that works.  I think it's because `ReplaceAll` works from the outside in as explained here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188608/86543 but I feel unsafe using that as I am not entirely sure.

- **Option 3**

Convenient:

(The code below uses the resource function [ReplaceAllOutside](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ReplaceAllOutside))

```
 expression3=
(Expand[(x + Cos[x[2] + x]*x[2]*x + Sin[x[3]*x])^2 + x] // 
 ResourceFunction["ReplaceAllOutside"][x :> x1, x[_]]);
```

**Check:**

```
expression1 == expression2 == expression3
```

`True`