# How to drop `Infinity` AND 'Indeterminate' elements from an equation?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

This is a simple question but somehow after trying `Delete`, and `Drop` I still cannot get what I want. Given the following equation,

```
eq = (-0.818158 + 
0.725806 Log[0.683526 λ[1., 2.]] λ[1., 2.] + 
0.774194 Log[0.744189 λ[2., 1.]] λ[2., 1.] + 
0.774194 Log[0.744189 λ[2., 3.]] λ[2., 
 3.])/(0.951613 - 0.725806 (0.0444444 + λ[1., 2.]) - 
0.774194 (0.0208333 + λ[2., 1.] + λ[2., 3.]));
```

I want to drop from this equation all the terms that involve `Lambda`. (A `term` is an element between two arithmetic signs like `+` and `-`.) because the `Lambda` is equal to zero and taking `Log[0]` is infinite. So, I like to get rid of `Infinity` and have a real number as a solution.

Generally speaking, given a list of very large equations, I like to drop `Lambda terms with zero` from all the equations.

I think it is easier to drop all the terms that generate infinity.

Comment: So you mean something like `eq/.s_Plus:>Select[s,FreeQ[λ]]`?

Comment: @Lukas Lang: Somehow your result is not equal to the result I obtain by simply dropping the lambda terms manually. I do not really know why? Is it possible to show the term remaining after dropping the lambda terms. This will let me know why I get two different results.

Comment: It helps if you show what the desired output should be from the given input.

Comment: @Nasser: `-0.905818` is the result I obtain from the equation by manually dropping the infinity terms. Lukas's result is `-0.859759`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that there's anything wrong with the answer by @Nasser and I have upvoted, but since there are some complains below is an alternative.

Logic:

1. Split the equation to a [**`List`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)
2. Evaluate all the terms of the aforementioned [**`List`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) for the value of $\lambda$ that causes the infinity
3. Drop infinities
4. Sum the elements

It works roughly like this:

With

```
eq = (-0.818158 + 
     0.725806 Log[0.683526 λ[1., 2.]] λ[1., 2.] + 
     0.774194 Log[0.744189 λ[2., 1.]] λ[2., 1.] + 
     0.774194 Log[0.744189 λ[2., 3.]] λ[2., 
       3.])/(0.951613 - 0.725806 (0.0444444 + λ[1., 2.]) - 
     0.774194 (0.0208333 + λ[2., 1.] + λ[2., 3.]));
```

Create the list

```
List @@ (eq // Rationalize // Expand)
```

output is:

> [image: list1]

Impose the condition that $\lambda$ is zero

```
List @@ (eq // Rationalize // Expand) /. λ[_, _] -> 0
```

with the output

> [image: list2]

**Observe that Mathematica yields `Indeterminate` and not Infinity**

Then, we proceed as

```
Select[List @@ (eq // Rationalize // Expand) /. λ[_, _] -> 0, 
 FreeQ[Indeterminate]]
```

> [image: res]

If there were more finite numerical elements you could do a [**`Total`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)

Addendum: demonstrating what I mentioned at the end.

Consider the following equation, which is the original with the modification that I added a `3`

```
eq = (-0.818158 + 
     0.725806 Log[0.683526 λ[1., 2.]] λ[1., 2.] + 
     0.774194 Log[0.744189 λ[2., 1.]] λ[2., 1.] + 
     0.774194 Log[0.744189 λ[2., 3.]] λ[2., 
       3.])/(0.951613 - 0.725806 (0.0444444 + λ[1., 2.]) - 
     0.774194 (0.0208333 + λ[2., 1.] + λ[2., 3.])) + 3;
```

Then

```
Total@(Select[
   List @@ (eq // Rationalize // Expand) /. λ[_, _] -> 0, 
   FreeQ[Indeterminate]])
```

gives back

> [image: res2]

Comment: Yes, the process you described is what I was thinking but could not code it. That is exactly what I wanted to obtain. I noticed `Indeterminate` terms which I wanted to drop as well. So, your answer works well for me. I did not mean that Naser's answer is not good. It was too complicated for me to follow. I can follow your answer better.

Comment: @TugrulTemel glad I was able to help :-) Regarding the answer by Nasser, I just added the comment for clarity, in the sense that what he suggested does not break down, or cause any issues because I tried it. That was all :-)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your and Nasser's help. My model works very nicely generating the desired outputs.

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for this limit?

```
Limit[eq, {λ[1., 2.] -> 0, λ[2., 1.] -> 0, λ[2., 3.] -> 0}]
(*    -0.905818    *)
```

With automatic generation of the list of $\lambda$ variables:

```
Λ = Union[Cases[eq, λ[___], ∞]]
(*    {λ[1., 2.], λ[2., 1.], λ[2., 3.]}    *)

Limit[eq, Thread[Λ -> 0]]
(*    -0.905818    *)
```

Comment: A very compact answer. Earlier, I did not understand the code but now I see the value. Thanks.

Comment: I think your answer above is not a general solution to my question because in your formulation `Log[a lambda]` will go to `-Infinity`; however, I want to prevent this to happen and hence to drop it from the equation. Basically, I want to drop all `Indeterminate` and `Infinity` terms from the equation because zero terms are irrelevant in my equation.

Comment: I was assuming that you are simply taking the limit of all $\lambda$ values going to zero, and making use of the limit $\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=0$. This limit expresses your intent: the zero is “stronger” than the infinity and their product tends to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tried your `Code` with `lamda` and `game` and `alpha` simultaneously`, but cannot get it right. Is there a way to expand the list of zero-parameters to include others in a one-line code?

Comment: Try `Union[Level[eq, {-2}]]` but it depends a lot on your variables.

Answer (score 6):

> -0.905818 is the result I obtain from the equation by manually dropping the infinity terms.

In this case you could try

```
eq /. Log[_ * λ[_, _]] -> 1 /. λ[_, _] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if you want to keep the λ, and only remove the log terms, you can try

```
eq /. Log[_ * λ[_, _]] -> 1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know if this will work for all your expressions. I only tried it on the one you gave.

Comment: Your answer is good but not the solution I am after. My main problem is that some terms in the equation are `infinite` due to several reasons: either `Log[0]` or a term divided by `zero`. Instead of struggling to find those terms with `Lamda`, I simply drop the terms that lead to `infinity`. I think if I can drop the terms that lead to `infinity`, it will be an answer to my question.

Comment: @TugrulTemel may be you could then give additional examples of expressions and desired output of each in order to be able to come up with a general solution that works for all. Right now you only have one example and hard to make a general solution from that one example only.

Comment: Dropping all terms that involve `infinity` is a general solution. It really does not matter which example I give because the process of getting `infinite` is not relevant. The only relevant information is the fact that I end up with `infinite` terms, which I want to drop from the equation.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version of my original suggestion that gives the desired result:

```
Replace[eq, s : Except[_?AtomQ, _Plus] :> Select[s, FreeQ[λ]], All]
(* -0.905818 *)
```

The original version used `ReplaceAll` instead of `Replace[...,All]`, which resulted in the `λ` terms being deleted at the outermost level, rather than at the innermost level (see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/is-there-a-difference-between-replace-with-parameter-all-and-replaceall)).

The other trick that is required is `Except[_?AtomQ,_Plus]` instead of simply `_Plus`. This is needed because `_Plus` also matches atoms such as `1` due to the `OneIdentity` attribute of `Plus`, which then breaks `Select`